react project cannot get the data from the contract
I copied a project and there is a problem when ( tried to access the page of my react app it shows "failed to fetch"
ERROR
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HttpProvider.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:90127:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:90099:67
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:90081:10)
    at HttpProvider.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:90125:12)
    at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67163:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67037:67
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

I am using the same account address to access the project using MetaMask and make sure the contract is successfuly connected but I cannot access it on my local. I already install all the package using npm install and npm install web3 to install the web3 package. Can you tell me where is the problem?
Here is the code of my contract.js
import Web3 from 'web3';

const CONTRACT_ABI = [
    
        {
            "inputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "approver",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "currentApprovals",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "approvalsRequired",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Approval",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate1",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate2",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "invalidVotes",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "ipfsLink",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "VotesAdded",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate1",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate2",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "invalidVotes",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "ipfsLink",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "VotesFinalized",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate1",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate2",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "invalidVotes",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "ipfsLink",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "VotesStaged",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "approve",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "address[]",
                    "name": "_approvers",
                    "type": "address[]"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_approvalsRequired",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "createVoteSession",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "getApprovers",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "address[]",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "address[]"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "getStagedVotes",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate1",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "candidate2",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "invalidVotes",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "ipfsLink",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "getVoteSession",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "candidate1",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "candidate2",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "invalidVotes",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                            "internalType": "string",
                            "name": "ipfsLink",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ],
                    "internalType": "struct Pemilu.VoteCounts",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "tuple"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "address[]",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "address[]"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "owner",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "sessionId",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_candidate1",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_candidate2",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "_invalidVotes",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "_ipfsLink",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "stageVotes",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    
];

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x80177985203443834F4DAeB315B77d8EF104A9D7';  // Replace with your deployed contract address

const getContractInstance = async () => {
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545');
  const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

  return { instance, web3 };
};

export default getContractInstance;


What RPC provider are you using? If you’re using local node, make sure that it’s running at 7545 port, otherwise you might have to change the port in your code accordingly.

i am using amoy testnet network not on my local node.

Okay, and the injected provider that you’re using is of your MetaMask?

yes and the DApps should connect to the MetaMask, but still encounter an error cannot fetch data even thought i was install the web3.js package on my react project

Can you console log your Web3.givenProvider to see whether it’s correctly initialised or not?
